# assistance with sh creation

Tags: shell-script

I'd like some assistance with turning the below commands into an executable shell script (?sh?)

```
sudo su  
export SLOTS=/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots  
cd /lib/firmware  
echo PRU-GPIO-Enable > $SLOTS  
exit
```

I have attempted to grasp the concepts of wrappers and call-ins but for now this simple task is out of my grasp.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just create a file with extension .sh and paste the comments. It's better to use a shebang. And don't forget to chmod after you've created the file

Comment: Doesn't work :/, i've read that the su and cd commands are the issue but im stuck on how to resolve  it

Comment: Yeah, to use su you must use a terminal. But `cd` should work fine. Why not remove the su part and run the script with `sudo`?

Comment: removed the su still no dice, running the commands indivudally is fine but i need these in a sh to run on boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem you want the exact code that you typed out to be runable as a shell-script?

```
echo "
#!/bin/bash
export SLOTS=/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots
cd /lib/firmware
echo PRU-GPIO-Enable > $SLOTS
exit" > file && chmod +x file
```

I removed the `sudo su` as I believe it better that you run the script using `sudo` and I am not sure what problems it might give you trying to set user from a script.

Or to break it down, create a file and add the contents to the file using a text editor (vim, emacs or nano perhaps). I've added the first line to it to let it know what shell to use while executing, since bash is often enough default I went with that.

Then you save the file to a named file, I called it *file*.

This file needs execution rights, so I `chmod +x` on the file to make it executable.

now you can run the script `$ ./file`

I might have completely missed the problem you are trying to solve, but hopefully I could help.

Comment: Thank you very much! that did the trick and script is working great now

Comment: Glad to hear, always fun to be able to help ^^

Answer (score 2):

The only part of this script that requires the ability to run as root is the writing to the kernel configuration parameter. The `cd` is also redundant because nothing uses it.

So the script can be rewritten like this

```
#!/bin/bash
export SLOTS=/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots
echo PRU-GPIO-Enable | sudo tee $SLOTS >/dev/null
exit
```

Remember to make the script file executable, and if appropriate drop it into your `$PATH`. (I use either `/usr/local/bin/` or `$HOME/bin` depending on the context, both of which are always in my `$PATH`.)

Or use this one-liner

```
echo PRU-GPIO-Enable | sudo tee /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots >/dev/null
```

Comment: the `exit` is redundant too, because that's what script interpreters do when there's no more script to interpret.  Also, why wrap the one-liner version in `bash -c`?

Comment: @cas I left the `exit` because I think it's "good form" to show an explicit end point in a script. Just about all my scripts end with an explicit exit status, though, rather than this implicit approach. Re the `bash` wrapping, that's simply because I forgot to remove it when I moved the `sudo` from the front of the entire line to just the `tee`. Fixing now...